# SQL Server SELECT STUFF returning incorrect values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used STUFF in the past and with no problems but this one is a little different. Maybe due to the table structure. I have set up some nice testing script if anyone wants to take a look at it. Any input is appreciated.

```
DECLARE @DetailTbl TABLE(DetailID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Roll VARCHAR(6))
INSERT INTO @DetailTbl (Roll) VALUES ('ABC')
INSERT INTO @DetailTbl (Roll) VALUES ('DEF')
INSERT INTO @DetailTbl (Roll) VALUES ('JKL')
INSERT INTO @DetailTbl (Roll) VALUES ('MNO')

DECLARE @RunTbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, Run VARCHAR(6))
INSERT INTO @RunTbl (Run) VALUES ('X12')
INSERT INTO @RunTbl (Run) VALUES ('Y34')
INSERT INTO @RunTbl (Run) VALUES ('Z56')

DECLARE @RunRollRef TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, RunID INT, DetailID INT)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (2, 4)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (3, 2)
INSERT INTO @RunRollRef (RunID, DetailID) VALUES (3, 3)

SELECT rt.ID,

(SELECT
STUFF((SELECT dt.Roll + ','
FROM @DetailTbl dt
INNER JOIN @RunRollRef ref ON ref.DetailID = dt.DetailID
WHERE dt.DetailID = r.DetailID
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')) 
AS Rolls

FROM @RunTbl rt
INNER JOIN @RunRollRef r ON r.RunID = rt.ID

--Expected Output
--1 ABC,DEF,JKL,
--2 MNO,ABC,
--3 DEF,JKL,
```

Comment: You aren't using STUFF, you're using the XML string aggregation technique. If you get unexpected results, it's not *STUFF* that causes the problem. Either `GROUP BY` statement is wrong (or missing), or the input contained characters that need escaping before they are used in XML.

Comment: What is the *actual* output? You haven't used a `GROUP BY` clause so you'll get one row for every join combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have too many joins and are not removing the delimiter correctly.  Try this:

```
SELECT rt.ID,
       (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + dt.Roll
                      FROM @DetailTbl dt JOIN
                           @RunRollRef ref
                           ON ref.DetailID = dt.DetailID
                      WHERE ref.RunID = rt.ID
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
                            ), 1, 1, '')
                    ) AS Rolls
FROM @RunTbl rt;
```

Note the changes:

- You don't need the `JOIN` in the outer query.
- The `','` is *prepended* not post-pended.
- The correlation condition in the subquery needs to be fixed.
- The third argument to `stuff()` should be `1`, not `0`.  (Replacing no characters with an empty string doesn't do anything.)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
select rt.ID, stuff(tt.Rolls, 1, 1, '') as Rolls
from @RunTbl rt outer apply
     ( select ', '+dt.Roll
       from @RunRollRef rf inner join
            @DetailTbl dt
            on dt.DetailID = rf.DetailID
       where rf.RunID = rt.ID
       for xml path('')
     ) tt(Rolls);
```

The outer `select` has unnecessary `JOIN`s which is really not needed.

You need to referenced `ref.RunID = rt.ID` instead of `dt.DetailID = r.DetailID` in subquery.